# Prestigio PMP7100D3G tablet, empty adb devices

Tags: android, list, sdk, adb, device

I just want to start developing on Android and I've got tablet 'Prestigio PMP7100D3G'... I followed whole tutorial on 'developer.android.com' about ADB connecting + installing. So Ive got installed OEM USB Driver (from SDK manager) and set 'Android ADB interface' (there were also 'Android Composite ADB Interface', but i choosed this one)

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTNOp.png

But in console it shows empty 'List of devices attached' so in Eclipse SDK I can't run applications...

btw. I've got 'Windows 7 (32-bit)'

Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working adb.exe on the first link in the following XDA developers forum post:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1987280

1. Backup adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll and AdbWinUsbApi.dll from the platform-tools android SDK folder.
2. Download ROOT_icood70pro.zip from the first link in the provided forum thread
3. Extract adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll and AdbWinUsbApi.dll from the downloaded archive, and copy them to the platform-tools folder, overwriting existing files

You can check if there are devices available by using "adb devices".

Cheers, and hope this helps!